# Container_Unresponsive_Error

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, containers

I am getting a container unresponsive error for my R Shiny deployed code.

Can anyone help me in understanding what this error means and what should be my approach
to debug this?

I tried running the code locally as there might be errors like some data that the code is trying
to fetch is deleted from a shared location, or the code at a shared location might get changed.

The code still runs locally.

Comment: Deploying the same code again works, but I am still interested to learn what was the error